# Gremlin nested loops and double repeat statements

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

How does gremlin interpret double repeats such as described here for Lowest Common Ancestor algorithm? http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.3-SNAPSHOT/recipes/#_lowest_common_ancestor

It appears this is interpreted as a nested loop inside another loop O(n^2), rather than two independent loops. I would like to verify this behavior. Can I have a detailed explanation of the semantics here.

If this is behavior, is there a way to break the outer loop on condition of inner loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a nested `repeat()` (i.e. one `repeat()` inside another) - the first `repeat()` ends at the first `emit()` and then a new `repeat()` begins. It's thus saying that the traversal will first traverse `out()` emitting every vertex it comes across and each of those vertices will traverse `in()` only emitting the "D" vertex.

Nested loops were not supported in 3.2.3 and is actually only possible in the soon to be released 3.4.0 which you can read about [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/upgrade/#_nested_loop_support) and looks like this:

```
gremlin> g.V().repeat(__.in('traverses').repeat(__.in('develops')).emit()).emit().values('name')
==>stephen
==>matthias
==>marko
```

Here you can see a `repeat()` actually inside a `repeat()`